# PowerShell script to silent install .exe

Tags: powershell, installation, silent

I have to deploy an .exe silently for our employees. Although the program is very old and does not show any documentation of any parameters. The only parameter i could find is the silent install one which is /s

But.. once i execute the .exe with /s i get a prompt asking me to enter a password because the installer is protected with a password. I have the pass but is it possible to create a script in PS to automaticly enter the password? Normally it would be something like "/p *PASSWORD*" but none of those parameters are anywhere to be found.

Comment: I would look up `Sendkeys`

Comment: The thing is i want the installer.exe to not even give me a pop up asking for the password. But i can't find the correct parameter to give the password prior to installation.

Comment: What does the setup dialogs look like? Any clues to what tool was used to make them? Text, images. What does it say in the file properties for the executable? Maybe add a screenshot? What does it say when you go `setup.exe /?`.

Comment: The setup was made by "Wise Solution". And when i execute the .exe with /s behind it, it skips pretty much every screen except for the screen where it asks for the password.

I'm getting the feeling that the person who made this .exe installer either didn't include the parameter to silently give the password or was to lazy to include it in the /? screen.

I guess i have to make it an App-V package now.

Answer (score 0):

You commented:

> The thing is i want the installer.exe to not even give me a pop up asking for the password. But i can't find the correct parameter to give the password prior to installation.

Whether you can do that depends on how the installer is constructed. If it forces a GUI password prompt and does not provide a way to bypass that, then you cannot automate it reliably.

Alternatively: You could use a reference computer (a virtual machine would work well for this), use a snapshot tool that can log all changes to the file system and registry, run your installer, record the changes, and then build your own installer that doesn't require the password.

This question is probably much better suited to [superuser](https://superuser.com/), however.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess i have make it an App-V package.